# Javascript REGEX to take an array convert into string with {} each of the element

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In Javascript, I am trying to take an array and make it a string with curly braces with each word.

Input: ["apple", "brand", "title"]

Output should be: '{apple} {brand} {title}'

I tried with JSON.stingify or toString() however couldn't get the expected output. I have no knowledge about regex.

Later on I need to take '{apple} {brand} {title}' and convert back to array. Is there any way to accomplish this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
console.log(
  ["apple", "brand", "title"].map(el => `{${el}}`).join(' ')
);
```

Comment: Yes! Do you also know how can I do this backward? Take the string and convert to array?

Comment: `'{apple} {brand} {title}'.replace(/[{}]/g, '').split(' ')`

Comment: You are great! I will accept the answer whenever I can